# Perl Net::SFTP::Foreign password authentication . No key exchange setup can be done

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp

I got the Net::SFTP::Foreign module installed and it is being worked fine for the key-exchange sftp set-up. But I need to set it up to have password based authentication where it should take the password that I passed to login.

I have gone through multiple threads on this topic and found that it is somehow possible using IO:Pty module of Perl. Below is the command that I found to use.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    $host, 
    user => $user, 
    password => $password,
    more => [
        -o => 'PreferredAuthentications=password,keyboard-interactive,***publickey***'
    ],
);
```

But here, in the preferred authentications, the public key is also being passed.

Can anyone please help me on this? What is the public key that is being referred here?

Also, installing IO::Pty along with Net::SFTP::Foreign modules can server my requirement?

Please help.

Thanks and Regards,
Edu

Comment: Cross posted in PerlMonks: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1166664

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a point of using the Net::SFTP::Foreign, use the native Net::SFTP.

---

Anyway, the `PreferredAuthentications` just lists your preference order of authentication mechanisms. The `publickey` does not refer to any specific key. It just says that the Net::SFTP::Foreign should try first password authentication, if that fails, try keyboard-interactive authentication, and only, if even that fails, try the public key authentication. Obviously, if you do not specify any key pair, the public key authentication won't be tried, even if listed.

See also the `PreferredAuthentications` entry in the [`ssh_config` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config).

If you want to use the password authentication no matter what, there's no point listing the other methods, list just the password:

```
-o => 'PreferredAuthentications=password'
```

---

The IO:Pty is needed to implement the password authentication using 
the Net::SFTP::Foreign, but not when using the Net::SFTP (though that have other dependencies too).

Comment: Net::SFTP is 'pure perl', yet requires compiling some hairy math libraries. Net::SFTP::Foreign uses your system's existing 'ssh' command...IMO, it's the simpler and preferred library for sftp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just tried the below. and it worked fine.

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign ->new(host=> $ftp_address, user => $ftp_user_id, password => $ftp_password );
$sftp->$direction($ftp_source, $ftp_target, conversion => 'unix2dos' ) or die "put failed: " . $sftp->error; 

The job went fine with the valid input parameters. But in the command line, its showing the following message. 

SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP
password
Enter password for icrestb

Can you please advice on how to avoid getting this password message?

Thanks